# $f: X \to Y$ with $Y$ a topological space, find topology on $X$ s.t $f$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology

We are given a function $f: X \to Y$, and moreover, that $Y$ is a topological space. We are to determine if there is a topology on $X$ such that $f$ is continuous, and moreover, determine if this topology is unique.

Recall that a function $f$ is continuous if for every open set $V \in Y$ we have that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$. It is clear that we can define a topology on $X$ so that this holds. What I am having some problems with is the question of uniqueness: would it be correct to conclude that this topology is *not* unique, since all topologies on $X$ containing every $f^{-1}(V)$ meets this criteria, i.e all such topologies up to (finer) and including the discrete topology make $f$ continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost entirely correct in your conclusion. The topology is not *necessarily* unique. It is possible that the discrete topology is the *only* topology that will meet the criterion.

Answer (score 1):

You are arguing quite nice, actually. That is an example of a topology that would suite your needs (the quotient topology), the discrete topology would also suite very well indeed. I will denote the topology you OP just constructed by $\frac{Y}{f}$, quite similar to the notation used [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_%28topology%29). In fact, the only topologies that make $f$ to be continuous are the ones that are finer than $\frac{Y}{f}$, strictly speaking we would need to have a surjective function $f$.

Comment: We have yet to learn about the quotient topology, but I will keep your answer in the back of my head until the time comes :)

Comment: I think you have confused the names. The quotient topology (or *final topology*) is what we consider when we have a function $f:X\to Y$ from a space $X$ to a set $Y$, and it is then the finest topology on $Y$ such that $f$ is continuous. The dual concept, which you and the OP are describing here, is called *initial topology*.